# Low latency messaging software

Tags: messaging, tibco-rv

I have worked with TIBCO RV on applications that require low latency messaging. I have heard of projects where the team had to roll out their own socket code to get messages faster than the speed offered by RV.

Are there any tools out there, probably open source that can come close to or better than TIBCO RV?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) and [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).

RabbitMQ is designed for stability (it's very very hard to crash) and scalability (you can easily cluster more rabbits together to improve throughput).

ZeroMQ, on the other hand, is designed specifically for speed and efficiency, but is a bit lacking in features.

And if you need a middle-ground between the two, you can use the [RabbitMQ-ZeroMQ bridge](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/10/18/rabbitmq0mq-bridge/) (i.e. rabbit broker/zeromq clients).

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, with some good TCP/UDP protocol knowledge and good programming skills, it isn't that difficult. I've never seen TIBCO or like 29 West come close to a good, simple, specialized framework buit from the ground up.

If you are looking for speed better that TIBCO and the usual suspects, you are probably in that class of industry that you really should just bite the bullet and roll your own. I've written a couple of them, and as far as the messaging layer goes, I haven't seen anything available to help.

For like the protocol stack portion, you do have things like Open OnLoad to help.